# XSD for Alternating Elements

Tags: xml, xsd

I have the following XML shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<main>
  <bbcor Location="string" Name="string">
    <PipeDiameter_INCH>3.1415926535</PipeDiameter_INCH>
    <InitialPressure_PSI>3335.566</InitialPressure_PSI>
    <LWISE TotalSection="2">
      <DL_FT>535.00</DL_FT>            <HL_FT>653.00</HL_FT>
      <DL_FT>245.98</DL_FT>            <HL_FT>395.0</HL_FT>
    </LWISE>
  </bbcor>
</main>
```

I am trying to make a XSD validator for above file, but stuck in the alternating elements i.e.

```
<DL_FT>2.4</DL_FT> <HL_FT>234.00</HL_FT>
<DL_FT>3.5</DL_FT> <HL_FT>456.00</HL_FT>
<DL_FT>6.8</DL_FT> <HL_FT>678.00</HL_FT>
```

I tried online generators etc, but none provided the required XSD. The current XSD file is shown below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsd:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified"
            elementFormDefault="qualified" 
            version="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsd:element name="main">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element name="bbcor">
          <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
              <xsd:element name="PipeDiameter_INCH" type="xsd:decimal" />
              <xsd:element name="InitialPressure_PSI" type="xsd:decimal" />
              <xsd:element name="LWISE">
                <xsd:complexType>
                  <xsd:sequence>
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="DL_FT" type="xsd:decimal" />
                    <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="HL_FT" type="xsd:decimal" />
                  </xsd:sequence>
                  <xsd:attribute name="TotalSection" type="xsd:int" />
                </xsd:complexType>
              </xsd:element>
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="Location" type="xsd:string" />
            <xsd:attribute name="Name" type="xsd:string" />
          </xsd:complexType>
        </xsd:element>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
</xsd:schema>
```

What is wrong with the above XSD?   I am using xmllint to validate above XML file.
Does XSD not allow alternate elements? It worked when elements occurred like

```
<DL_FT>2.45</DL_FT> 
<DL_FT>2.44</DL_FT>
<DL_FT>2.35</DL_FT>
<HL_FT>245</HL_FT>
<HL_FT>445</HL_FT>
<HL_FT>545</HL_FT>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are very close.  Simply **factor `maxOccurs="unbounded"` out to the `xsd:sequence`.**

Specifically, change

```
              <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="DL_FT" type="xsd:decimal" />
                <xsd:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="HL_FT" type="xsd:decimal" />
              </xsd:sequence>
```

to

```
              <xsd:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xsd:element name="DL_FT" type="xsd:decimal" />
                <xsd:element name="HL_FT" type="xsd:decimal" />
              </xsd:sequence>
```

because it's `DL_FT`-`HL_FT` ***pairs*** that are meant to be repeated indefinitely.

---

**Update:**

## Half pairs

I was amiss in not mentioning that the above solution is simple *only* because your examples are pair-based.  (Thanks to Michael Kay for the reminder.)  Should you need to allow non-paired stragglers such as a lone `DL_FT` straggler after a normal pair,

```
<DL_FT>2.4</DL_FT> <HL_FT>234.00</HL_FT>
<DL_FT>3.5</DL_FT> <-- no HL_FT here -->
```

you'll run into a classic, hopelessly ambiguous, content model issue and won't be able to check such a pattern via XSD.  RELAX NG could represent the pattern, however.

Comment: There's a textbook problem, however, which is harder to solve: here the sequences allowed are for example ABAB, ABABA, ABABAB, and ABABABA. (For example, the record of a chess game with alternating white and black moves).

Comment: Thanks Mr. Hughes, currently there is much to do in the XML area. But due to the lack of interest of software giants XML is suffering... However, XML has greater power than any.